# Ghost sign "<" appearing in webpage but not in html code

Tags: html

While coding a webpage in HTML, I encountered a weird problem: a mysterious ghost sign `<` (the sign of "less than") magically appears between one of my `h1` header and a `table`.

My Code:

```html
<!-- Other contents -->
<h1>Actual Table</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><font style="color: blue">Skill Name</font></th>
        <th><font style="color: magenta">Links</font></th>
    </tr>
    <!-- Other table rows goes here -->
</table>
```

This is what it looks like in the browser:
[Screenshot of webpage, the `<` sign in red rectangle is the ghost sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwEIq.png)

This is the screenshot for my html code in vscode, in case you wonder if it is a typo:
[vscode code screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niLMx.png)

This is the screenshot of the browser inspector: [browser inspector screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVtzz.png)

I am using `vscode 1.45.1` as my IDE and Microsoft Edge Beta 83.0.478.37 as my browser. Both running the page with Live Server Extension and directly opening the html file generate the problem. I also tried Firefox and Chrome, but they all have the same problem.

Sorry that I cannot embed pictures.

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with the question but please get rid of font tags, we are not in the 20th century anymore.

Comment: Thanks that was indeed silly  a ```div``` could work just fine

Comment: Do you have any CSS with a `:before` or `:after` that's adding it? Do you have any JavaScript that's injecting it?

Comment: You don't even need a div. If you need to have the full color inside an element one color set a class on the wrapping element (th in this case) and use CSS.

Comment: There is no ```:before``` or ```:after``` in CSS; thanks for the advice on no double ```h1``` and no ```div```; in this case there is no comments in HTML as well. Thanks to you all :D

Comment: Does the HTML validate / pass validation?

Comment: @Power_tile Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.